# Incorrect NET-SNMP Version in BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: c++, linux, beagleboneblack, net-snmp, snmpd

I work with the Net-SNMP library with C++ on an Debian inside a beaglebone back. I used to work with net-snmp 5.7.1 version. However, I need to upgrade it to 5.9. I did the steps of this tutorial: http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2013/08/compiling-and-installing-net-snmp-for-beaglebone/, but I changed the configuration step to just:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --build=i686-linux --host=arm --target=arm-linux --with-ar=/home/ubuntu/angstrom-toolchain/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ar --with-cc=/home/ubuntu/angstrom-toolchain/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc --with-linkcc=/home/ubuntu/angstrom-toolchain/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

I updated the compiled files in the beagleboneblack, then I could see the version 5.9 when I executed the command:

```
$snmpd -version
```

I also updated the Libraries in the path of the G++ Linker, compiled and uploaded the C++ firmware to beaglebone.

However, inside the C++ firmware, when I call the funcion:
`init_snmp("agent");`
The output is:
`NET-SNMP version 5.7.1 AgentX subagent connected`

I was expecting the 5.9 version of it. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I saw here that after doing the tutorial to compile the net-snmp, it's not generating .so's files, just .a and .la files. I could not make it generate the necessary so's lib files. Any help?